# IPV6 issue on Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, kubuntu, network-manager

I have a new Kubuntu 18.04 installation which was done from scratch, which normally works ok. What I have noticed though, is that whenever certain updates cause a `ureadahead` reconfiguration on next reboot, when that next reboot takes place, the system cannot use IPV6 at all for some reason. `ping -6 -nc5 www.google.com` for example produces a *Network is unreachable* error.

I have created my own ethernet connection profile on *Network Connections* where IPV4 connection is **Manual** and IPV6 is **Automatic**. IPV4 connectivity works ok every time, whereas IPV6 is facing the problem I mentioned above.

If I restart the system at that point, everything goes back to normal and IPV6 connectivity is fully restored.

Any ideas please?

Comment: I'm having similar weird networking issues (e.g. not able to ping intermittently after coming out of suspend) with Kubuntu 18.  I disabled IPV6 to eliminate that being the issue, but hasn't helped.